# Where should I convert my entities to DTO's?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

My architecture looks like this:

- Domain

  - Entities
  - Interfaces
  - DTOs
- Infrastructure

  - ORM
  - Repositories
- Services

  - Web Services

I'm wanting to use AutoMapper to convert it. I would like my service layer to only know about DTOs, so I'm guessing I would have my Interfaces and my Repositories return the converted DTO. As for the other direction, I would assume that my Repositories will take DTOs and convert to Entities? Am I on the correct path here or am I in left field?

Comment: Who will consume your service and how?

Comment: My services will be accessed like an API into my internal system. Some will be inhouse, but down the road, out of house systems will be connecting

Comment: If its down the road or in house, services are easy to connect and hack into, your exposed end points (web services) should return secure DTO, which will not contain entire entities.

Comment: So maybe the correct solution is to map into DTO's for my Service layer, but out of my repositories, map to ViewModels

Comment: Yes, services always return DTO, since we will send information only based on authentication and user access. However, we use dynamic serialization to avoid DTO making, it's painful. Dynamic serialization serializes only part of entity based on user who is logged in, and such rules are coded in database itself and out of code.

Comment: So what are your thoughts on returning ViewModels to a trusted consumer of the Services project (non-WCF). So like my web front end wanting to work with a service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13632/discussion-between-tyler-wright-and-akash-kava)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your repositories should only deal with domain aggregates, which are designed around  behaviors and transactions.
2. When processing commands, your application layer (web services) should invoke logic on the domain model, saving the aggregates back to the repositories.
3. When the client needs data from the web service you have two options:

   - Fetch aggregates from repositories and map them to POCO DTO's (maybe using AutoMapper).
   - Create a thin data-access layer specifically for querying data direct to DTO's.

The latter approach is my preference. As I said, domain aggregates **should** be designed by behavior & transactions. They are not designed to show data on a screen. It's always an awkward process trying to map data from a properly designed domain entity (i.e. properly encapsulated) to a DTO for a consumer of the data (such as a UI). It's square peg in a round hole. It is much easier in my opinion to provide a thin data access layer that returns whatever data the client requires. The domain model need not be involved in this process; it's just data. This is the basic principle of [CQRS](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/).

In any case it should be the application layer (web services) converting the domain entities to DTO's.

Comment: This seems like the best approach for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your service layer should return entities, and your presentation layer (where Controllers reside imho) should translate the entities to objects that map to your user interface (the DTOs). This, of course, also implies that your repositories will return normal entities.

Don't forget to create the mappings only once. Create a bootstrapper or something that creates all the mappings, then you only have to call Mapper.Map() in your controller.

Comment: Yep. You should work with your entities (that represent your model, I suppose) until your last *controlled* layer.

Comment: That is my problem though, my Entities use Iesi.Collections.ISet which can not be serialized for my service layers WCF Services. I see what you mean, but with my WCF service layer, would that change things?

Comment: Disagree unless his architecture guarantees that the entities follow the domain model and not the data model.

Comment: Im trying to follow a Domain first approach.

Comment: If you are doing domain first then you don't need DTOs, you need view models and those should be mapped in your interface layer, which in your case is the service layer, so I agree with Leon.

Comment: Why should service layer return entities? What about security?

Comment: Disagree. DTO's stand for **Data Transfer Objects**. e.g. For transferring between a web service to a client. Returning entities to a presentation layer which then converts them to a DTO defies the point in their existence! Also, if you've modeled your entities correctly, you won't be able to serialize them because most won't have default constructors.